# struts as a backend for Backbone js

Tags: json, backbone.js, struts2

I have an simple application in struts, where the action class simply returns a JSON object and i'm rendering it.. This works fine..BUt now i want to use Backbone.js to render the object(which is nothing but model) from struts..
1.How to fetch the model from struts?
2.What shd be the URL in this case?

I assumed it is possible to use the model from struts bcoz the Json object is returned whenever we call fetch() in backbone js.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Assume that your Model fetch() method will send the data to Struts2 action class in JSON format.

All you need to define the similar set of properties in your action class and use Struts2-JSON plugin to work both way.

Struts2 in independent of what you are using in you UI to send the data,all it require is the respected fields in your action class so that the pram interceptor can set the values in respected fields.

all you need to take care that the "content-type" must be "application/json" while sending JSON data from the UI to action class (with Struts2 JSON plugin)

Comment: Wat URL i shd giv to model in backbone js, to invoke action class of Struts?

Comment: @user641753: i believe you need to give action name which you have configured in your struts.xml file